# Apache 2.2 URL Rewrite not working

Tags: php, html, apache, url-rewriting

I am trying to do a URL Rewrite, but no matter how I try, it seems like the htaccess file do not functioning at all, and it is only returning the directory listing.

Can anyone tell me what else do I need to look at to make it work?

Regards

PlayKid

Comment: The main apache config probably doesn't allow rewriting in .htaccess or even allow overriding via htaccess at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have AllowOveride All set in your vhost conf file.